# дополнять значение в бд mysql+php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

я хочу чтобы в поле `results` с каждым запросом дополнялось значение, а не обновлялось. ну сохранить результаты теста. при каждом выборе варианта дописывать его. типа он ответил А потом С потом Б. и чтобы с каждым разом значение `results` менялось как `А`->`АС`->`АСБ`. можно ли так делать используя только одну переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `results`=concat(`results`, 'новое_значение');
WHERE [...]
```

Comment: к сожалению не работает `$mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `result`=`result`+'$text' WHERE `id`=$chatId");`

Comment: я решил тем что присваивал значение `result`  новому элементу, дополнял его и заново обновлял значение `result`

Comment: Прошу прощения, + работает только с числовыми значениями. Как результат string+int не будет работать. Изменил ответ для string'a